# Java project with uml

Tags: java, uml

[image: UML Diagram]

Hi friends!

I'm trying to do my homework. Now I am busy with the `Cone.java` part.

(F) balls >>> Flavor[]

How can I define that?

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Your question is very unspecific, try to add more information and have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @Atilla Did my answer answer your question or were you struggling with something else?

Comment: I've solved this issue . Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 0):

Well to break it down a bit for you.

`Cone` is a class that implements `Eatable`.

It has a field called balls. This is an array of type `Flavors`.

It also has two constructors. A basic constructor that has no arguments and a constructor that takes an array of type `Flavors`.

Finally it has a method called `eat`. This comes from the interface `Eatable`.

This would look a little like the following.

**Eatable.java**

```
public interface Eatable {
    void eat();
}
```

**Cone.java**

```
public class Cone implements Eatable {
    //The types of flavors
    public enum Flavors {
        STRAWBERRY,
        BANANA,
        CHOCOLATE,
        VANILLA,
        LEMON,
        STRACIATELLA,
        MOKKA,
        PISTACHE
    }

    //The field
    private Flavors[] balls;

    //The constructors
    //Constructor Basic
    public Cone() {
        balls = new Flavors[0];
    }

    //Constructor with Flavors
    public Cone(Flavors[] balls) {
        this.balls = balls;
    }

    //The methods
    //You should always use getters and setters
    //https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1568091/why-use-getters-and-setters-accessors

    //Getter
    public Flavors[] getBalls() {
        return balls;
    }

    //Setter
    public void setBalls(Flavors[] balls) {
        this.balls = balls;
    }

    //Your method from UML
    @Override
    public void eat() {
        //Whatever
    }
}
```

Comment: https://github.com/injecti0n/IceCreamShop
I've done with the project but i have still compiler error ... 
Can you please check my code?

Comment: @Atilla Sure, give me a minute

Comment: @Atilla I just ran it in Eclipse and there seemed to be no compilation issues. There is still an exception being thrown but that is your own exception so I assume you are handling that how you want

Comment: @Atilla Let me know if there is another issue. In the meantime if either me or Thomas answered your question to your satisfaction would you be able to hit the tick on one of our answers? It lets others know the issue has been resolved. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

This is simply a Dependency relation. You need to draw a dashed arrow from `Cone` to `Flavor`. This is because `Flavor` is an enumeration (the Mickeysoft or Eclipse notation you're using is wrong by the way, but you probably can't alter that except by staying away from the tool itself). The enumeration is used for `balls` to form an array of `Flavor`s.